# Sound persistence in WAV file in JAVA

Tags: java, audio

Is there any possibility to check if WAV file contains a sound (or silence)? Currently I write automated tests in JAVA and I need to analyse saved WAV if it contains sound or not.

Comment: What do you mean with silence? A corrupted file?

Comment: @Lasnik file is not corrupted. I record sound from line in port and save it as WAV. The idea was to check persistence of sound. But now I know, that it is not so simple because the sound is saved like eg noise. This is not that what I want, but for machine, for Java this is sound. Now I know, that I need to analyse the level of the sound recorded in WAV file.

Comment: You figured it out yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

To check if a wav file contains sound you should read it´s data.

To do that you should take a look at [reading from a sound file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter7.html#a114527).

For a simpler guide you could also take a look at [this resource](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html). It is especially for wav files.

Comment: Good suggestion. To expand on the first, the example code has a comment "here do something useful with the audio data". Steps would be to assemble the bytes into PCM, then inspect the PCM values. I'm not clear that the WavFile offers a way to inspect PCM. How would you go about doing this? This makes me think it could be helpful for people wishing to do this to add to the github/philfrei/AudioCue API the ability to inspect the PCM. I will add that to my TODO list.